# jQuery Cycle - more images

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slideshow, cycle

I have some problem with jQuery Cycle Plugin. I realized standart cycle but I want that 3 images appear for starting in one slideshow.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean have 3 images appear at once when the slideshow starts or have 3 images in total in a slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Jquery Rotator Cycle from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ They have an example of 3 images being shown at a time in a Jquery rotator. It can be found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/div.html